# x:Name causes compilation fail. Absence of it does not

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I'm making a custom control. It uses some libraries from NuGet, namely:

PanAndZoom

Wpf.Controls.PanAndZoom

Wpf.MatrixExtentions

There is only the usercontrol xaml, its code behind and a separate class in the entire project. They're as below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DesignSurface"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:paz="clr-namespace:Wpf.Controls.PanAndZoom;assembly=Wpf.Controls.PanAndZoom"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:stigzler.controls.WPF.Workspace"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Focusable="True"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <paz:ZoomBorder>
                <Canvas x:Name="DesignCanvas" Background="DarkOliveGreen"></Canvas>      
    </paz:ZoomBorder>

</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
Public Class DesignSurface

    Public Sub AddDesignItem(di As DesignItem)

        DesignCanvas.Children.Add(di)
        Canvas.SetLeft(di, di.Position.X)
        Canvas.SetTop(di, di.Position.Y)

    End Sub

End Class
```

And separate class:

```
Public Class DesignItem
    Inherits ContentControl

    Private _position As Point
    Public Property Position() As Point
        Get
            Return _position
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Point)
            _position = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _size As Size
    Public Property Size() As Size
        Get
            Return _size
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Size)
            _size = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Now this compiles and executes fine. However, if I change the xaml to this:

```
<paz:ZoomBorder x:Name="ZoomController">
```

On compile, I get:

`Type Wpf.Controls.PanAndZoomBorder is not defined`

My solution tree:

[image]

I did read another post about conflicting namespaces or something, but can't see how that relates to this scenario. A bizarre bug - does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Where is `UserControl_Loaded` defined?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah wasn't that. Just forgot to include it in the code behind.